# entityNew fails

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have some stats code for ORM it lists out all the entities within the system.
I know the object is loaded and exists. But I get an error when trying to create a new entity.

```
Error: Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface {object name}
```

The code I am using to create the entity is simple.

```
o = entityNew("name");
o.setName("name of user");
entitySave(o);
```

It fails on the `entityNew()` line of code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is usually because your object isn't in the folder specified by your Application settings. You mentioned that you have other objects are working correctly, so you need to double check your code against the working code to see where the differences are.

The other thing you can do to make this work, is to reference the full CFC path to the object:

```
o = EntityNew("MyCFCs.ORM.Name");
```

I'd also (just because it makes me nervous to use reserved words) rename your CFC from `name` to something else (if that is indeed the name of your CFC).

Comment: The entity is called commodity, I was just using a simple example.

well i have a mapping setup for ORM and my ormsettings point to the path where the files live. some of the entities work fine. others dont and they are in the same folder. Also the ORMStats page shows all the entities being loaded.

I can create an object directly to the files and dump them ok. I have not tried the entityNew("full.path.to.file") approach and that might work fine but i should not have to do that.

Also I am getting strange issues with other things like createObject() and CF saying the file is missing.